# How to make load script that load multiple files in to one table

Tags: qlikview

I have multiple files named by convention: "data_YYYY.MM.xslx"
I need to load all these files to one qlikview table, but when I do:

```
Tab:
load Name, Number from [data_*.csv];
```

I get Tab, Tab-1, Tab-2 files for each file.

I`ve also tryed to do:

```
Tab:
add load Name, Number from [data_*.csv];
```

With the same effect.

If anybody know the way how to do it, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hack works for me:

```
tmp:
LOAD @1 inline [@1];
Tab:
Concatenate load Name, Number from [data_*.csv];
```

Comment: Thanks, the concatenate load works. For my case:  load Name, Number from [data_*.csv];  now will only create 2 table, but connected using synthetic key, which I do not like.

Answer (score 5):

This question makes no sense, unless you have omitted some detail.

QlikView **will** implicitly append all data to the original table 'Tab' by a statement such as:

Tab:
load Name, Number from [data_*.csv] (txt);

*Note the file format specified in brackets.*

Appending data implicitly occurs when ever a table is loaded with exactly the same field names as a table already created. So in your example, the first file encountered constitutes a load of data from that file. Assuming the field names are indeed referenced as per your question, the resultant table should have two fields in it: 'Name' and 'Number'. When the second file is encountered via the wildcard match, the second load takes place and it will append that data to the table 'Tab'.

If you wish to NOT rely upon IMPLICIT concatenation (QlikView terminology for appending data to an existing table) then you can write a FOR loop to load your files instead whist using the explicit CONCATENATE load prefix to point to the table you wish to append data to.

E.g.

// QV trick to 'declare' a table

Tab:
LOAD null() AS Name
AUTOGENERATE(1)
WHERE RecNo() < 0;

FOR EACH file IN filelist('data_*.csv')

CONCATENATE('Tab')
LOAD * FROM [$(file)] (txt);

NEXT file

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way:

```
Load * from data_*.csv;
```

Simply use a mask in the file name.

Comment: SPASIBO (Thanks) Fedya! With your way I get Tab, Tab-1, Tab-2 tables for each file. Look at my question.

Answer (score 1):

And for completeness one way with a loop (here using qvd files):

```
FOR Each db_schema in '2013-07','2013-08','2013-09'
LOAD ...., db_schema
FROM `x-$(db_schema)`.`qvd` (qvd);
next;
```

(Knowing the names.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way if the files names are different

Tab:
load Name, Number from [data_1.csv];
join (Tab)
load Name, Number from [data_2.csv];

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your way will work if names static and are known before. I sure this will be helpful for some one.